# Can not create a mobil in azure recieve The upstream server reported that the resource was not found

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to create a mobile service with a new database that I just provisioned, But when I do so I receive the below error. I have plenty of credit on my account. Does anyone know how to resolve the below error.

RDFE: The upstream server reported that the resource was not found. If you contact a support representative please include this correlation identifier: f328fe2f-15bd-785e-9048-2ba766cef4bf, the time of error: 2015-02-25 04:43:29Z, and the error id: ZE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve you will need to contact Microsoft support to resolve. There is something incorrect in the Metadata of the account and Microsoft will need to resolve it on their end. Microsoft just put out a patch yesterday that resolved the issue for me.